# How to add target="_parent" to all menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, target

I have a menu:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="about.html">about</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I add the target="_parent" to all links with the class "menu-item". How can I do this with jquery

Comment: If there are no other `li` in the `ul` put the class on the `ul`. And instead of using jquery put the `target="_parent"` in the html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$('.menu-item').attr('target', '_parent');
```

as you commented, if the menu-item class is attached to li elements then do;

```
$('.menu-item > a').attr('target', '_parent');
```

Comment: Ooh, forgot one thing, have the classes on the "li" not on the "a"

Comment: you forgot to add jquery in the jsfiddle you post. check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/keune/VmpXU/

Answer (score 1):

Or as an addition to the answer from keune for modern jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.menu-item').prop('target', '_parent');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item"> <a href="about.html">about</a>

    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"> <a href="contact.html">contact</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is `target` a property? I thought it was an attribute?

Comment: Sorry, forgot one thing, have the classes on the "li" not on the "a"